# Configure different components for same route name in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm looking to configure different components for a route

The application has different teams based on the selection I want to load the component.

TeamA-Componenet1
TeamB-Compoenent2
TeamC-Componenet3

The route path will be same for all 3.
/home/abc

I have tried route guards I also tried adding routes dynamically.

Below is the code:

```
let appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      component: appComponent,
      data: { title: 'app' },
      children: [
      
          {
            path: 'table',
            component: tableComponent,
            data: { title: 'appTable' }
          },
          
        ]
  }
 ];


export class AppRoutingModule {

  selectedTeam: any;

  constructor(public AppService: AppService,public router:Router) { 

    this.appService.selectedTeam.subscribe((team) => {
      this.selectedTeam=team[0].id;
      let selRouteIndex=appRoutes[0].children.findIndex((route) => route.path==='abc');
      appRoutes[0].children.splice(selRouteIndex, 1);

      if (this.selectedTeam==="TeamA") {
        appRoutes[0].children.push({
          path: 'abc',
          component: ComponentA,
          data: { title: 'MyApp' }
        })
       // this.router.resetConfig(otaDbRoutes);

      }
      else {
        appRoutes[0].children.push({
          path: 'abc',
          component: ComponentB,
          data: { title: 'MyApp' }
        })
        //this.router.resetConfig(otaDbRoutes);

      }

    });
  }
 }
```

This approach is nor working and it loads the first component always.

Please guide.

Thanks
Shruti Nair